# Seed failing with Rails4

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Windows 8.1
Rails 4.1
Ruby 2.0.0

This is what I have in my user.rb (model):

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable,
         :password_expirable, :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable

  if :work_phone != nil
    phony_normalize :work_phone, :default_country_code => 'US'
  end
  if :mobile_phone != nil
    phony_normalize :mobile_phone, :default_country_code => 'US'
  end
  if :fax_phone != nil
    phony_normalize :fax_phone, :default_country_code => 'US'
  end
  if :other_phone != nil
    phony_normalize :other_phone, :default_country_code => 'US'
  end
  validates :first, presence: true
  validates :last, presence: true
  validates :organization, presence: true
  validates_plausible_phone :work_phone
  validates_plausible_phone :mobile_phone
  validates_plausible_phone :fax_phone
  validates_plausible_phone :other_phone
  validates :email, :email => true, presence: true, uniqueness: {case_sensitive: false}
  before_save { |user| user.email = email.downcase }
end
```

and this is what I have in my seeds.rb:

```
user = User.new(
                :email =>'test@acme.net',
                :password =>'Vb%69Krn#',
                :password_confirmation =>'Vb%69Krn#',
                :first =>'John',
                :last =>'Doe',
                :salutation =>'Doe',
                :organization =>'Doe Test',
                :work_phone =>'555-555-5555',
                :mobile_phone =>'555-555-5555',
                :fax_phone =>'555-555-5555',
                :other_phone =>'555-555-5555',
                :address1 =>'One Main Street',
                :city =>'Anytown',
                :state =>'WA',
                :zip =>'98011',
                :role =>'admin'
                )
user.skip_confirmation!
user.save
```

When I do rake db:seed, I get the following error message:

```
rake aborted!
NoMethodError: undefined method `password_changed_at_changed?' for #<User:0x00000005f2b458>
C:/projects/rails/doe/db/seeds.rb:27:in `<top (required)>'
-e:1:in `load'
-e:1:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:seed
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a a problem with [devise_security_extension](https://github.com/phatworx/devise_security_extension). You have setted `password_expirable` but you probably didn't do this :

```
create_table :the_resources do |t|
  # other devise fields

  t.datetime :password_changed_at
end
add_index :the_resources, :password_changed_at
```

As it said in [the documentation](https://github.com/phatworx/devise_security_extension#password-expirable).

Comment: Yes, I forgot the password_changed_at column. This fixes it.